# ColdFusion dynamic placeholders

Tags: coldfusion

I'm writing a page generator to generate ColdFusion templates. I use placeholders (or whatever they're called) where the code shouldn't run immediately.

The following works OK and dumps a valid query object:

```
<%cfdump var = "#qPages#"%>
```

But the following attempt to loop through the above query throws the error: "Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values."

```
<%cfloop query = "#qPages#"%>
```

This also throws the same error:

```
<%cfloop query = "<%=qPages=%>"%>
```

What am I doing wrong?

(I'm running CF8.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `<cfloop>` expects a query *name*, not a query object.  Try this:

```
<%cfloop query = "qPages"%>
```